# How to prefetch data from api for 'ShowModalBottomSheet' even before it being opened in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to use `ShowModalBottomSheet` in my flutter App. But right now how it's being worked is the data which need to be displayed is being fetched only when `ShowModalBottomSheet` code executed and which creating a delay.

I want to know how do I prefetch the data beforhand using Future so that which can be used instantly when `ShowModalBottomSheet` triggered.

Comment: can you share some code to make the problem clearer please

Comment: You can fetch the data somewhere higher in the tree and pass it down.

Answer (score -1):

You could use and create a [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or `bloc`, and load the data, whenever the application's starts or the page is opened. 
This way, the data will be available before the bottom sheet opens.